# edit html content in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, edit, jtextpane

I really need your help as I'm trying for one month now to do something using various approaches... unsuccessfully.

I have a JTextPane containing a html text with images, etc. This works perfectly.

Now, I have the id of a < span > < /span > element and I want to delete it's content and insert a component instead.

More concretely, I have : < span id='123' >< img src='url/123.png' / >< /span >
and I want to have < span id='123' >#JLabel< /span >

I know how to :

- get the span Element : htmlDoc.getElement("123");
- insert a JLabel in the JTextPane at the caret position : jtp.insertComponent(component);

I have no idea how I can :

- delete the < img / >
- insert my component at the proper position.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to get the Span Element so maybe the following will work:

1. The Element class has a getStartOffset() method which you might be able to use to insert the JLabel.
2. Take a look at HTMLDocument class. There is a remove(Element) method.

Comment: I didn't found the remove(Element) method. Are you sure to talk about the class javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument ?
Anyway, thanks to you I found setInnerHTML and setOuterHTML that solved the problem of removing the img element.
About the insertion, your solution works perfectly.
Thank you so much for your answer !
(By the way, in the case of an img inside a span, the HTMLDocument.getElement(id) method has a very weird behaviour. The span Element is completely ignored...)

Comment: HTMLDocument inherits this method from another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to do it. Here's an example of one that makes what you want, but does not handle whitespaces:

```
<img src='.+?'(/>|></img>)
```

In your example, if you ignore whitespaces, it would be like this:

```
String html = "< span id='123' ><img src='url/123.png'/>< /span >";
String newValue = html.replaceFirst("<img src='.+?'(/>|></img>)", "myJLabel");
```

To make it work with whitespaces, just add `\s*` wherever they can appear. Here's an example that allow both `<img` and `< img`

```
<\\s*img src='.+?'(/>|></img>)
```

Now, to make it work as you need, just put the others `\s*` where you think it's necessary

To learn more about regex, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Ok. My fault if I wasn't clear.
the spaces where just to make the html appear on my message. Otherwise your browser will interpret it
"replaceFirst" requests "String, String" as an argument. myJLabel is, of course, a JLabel. I don't think I can use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

why are you adding a jlabel to a TextPane?

anyway, since HTML is a XML-dialect, you could use a XML-parser to organize your tags and change contents and attributes.

so you could update the content of your Text-Pane by simply calling setText()

Comment: Actually one of the reasons is that I'm using JEuclide to represent mathML expressions. JEuclide represents it using a JMathComponent that I have to insert into the textpane.
My issue is that I can't add the component to the html. I have to add it to the textPane. With your solution, how and when am I supposed to add it ?